# Self-sizing static table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have got a static table view with 5 cells. Each cell has a text field (one line) to enter different user details. Last cell is the address cell which is supposed to be multi line. I wonder if I can make the cell expanding while the user enters her address. I want the last cell to have the same height as the previous 4 but I want it to expand as the user enters data (in a text view for instance, or even a text field with its frame modified). Is that even possible?